# How I I deploy a Vue JS app still in development in my Go Daddy hosting?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue JS app still in development and would like to deploy it in a shared hosting such as Go daddy. This is for me to see the progress of my app online on mobile devices.

Do I need to run 'npm run build' since I will be making changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "since I will be making changes"?

Comment: Yes, `npm run build` then upload `/dist` contents.  Any changes will have to be rebuilt and uploaded.  If you're asking whether it will [hot reload](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html) after saving changes, as it does locally in development mode: no.  If your goal is to preview mobile development, it's very easy to emulate devices with Chrome's [Device Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Surge.sh](https://surge.sh/) to deploy your app. Once you are done you can destroy it.

Steps to deploy Vue application on Surge.sh

1. `npm run build`
2. `npm install --global surge`
3. `surge dist\`
4. Create an account or log in on existing one
5. Surge gives you the option to add a preferred subdomain or you can you the given one.
6. Done!

Steps to update your existing deployed app on surge

1. `npm run build`
2. `surge dist\`
3. Add your domain
4. Done!

Steps to destroy your deployed app from Surge.sh

1. `surge teardown your-sub-domain.surge.sh`
2. Done!

I found this option a better temporary solution until you finally deploy your latest version of your application.